# What is the optimal way of monitoring if PostgreSQL table records' date field is today?

Tags: postgresql

I am quite new to PostgreSQL administration and currently developing a .NET application that uses **PostgreSQL 11** as DB engine.

I have a task at hand to send notifications to users whose service plan is about to run out or discontinue services for those whose plan did run out. I want to make it more efficient, without periodically running through all the records (of which there can be great amount).
All dates of end of their plans are stored in a table that has 1-1 relation to user entity.

**The question is:**
Is there a way to start a countdown when the date field is modified and fire an event that sends signal to external application when this timer runs out? Or are there any functions that can help me to achieve the similar results? And what mechanism should I use to communicate with my .NET application?

I hope what I'm describing makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to start a countdown when the date field is modified and fire an event that sends signal to external application when this timer runs out?

Short answer: No.

What would happen if your database was stopped and restarted?
How could it "restart" all of those timers?

You might be able to do something with triggers, but it's probably not worth the effort.

It's far more common (and simpler) to do what you say you *don't* want to do; write a program to scan through the records and find those that are "soon" to be discontinued or that already have been (and that you haven't previously done anything about).